# Support the suggested Music Production SE

Tags: discussion, scope

I believe the suggested [Music Production SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82083/music-production) has merits, and that people here interested in this subject should support it.

While some of the subject(s) might technically be on topic here, I don't think we have he expertise in the current user group, based on the few questions of this type we have. I don't think we are attracting more of the music production type users, nor do I see how we would go about doing that.

I think these questions are best suited with a dedicated forum, if you agree, please support it. If you disagree, I'm interested in hearing how we might improve the current situation here.

For the downvoters, I'm genuinely interested in if you think what we have works, if the questions should be on another existing SE like Sound Design, or if it's something else. (As rep doesn't really count on Meta, and I downvote heavily myself on things I don't agree with, it's not about hurt feelings.)

Comment: Hey there, just wondered how much overlap this might have with sound.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BobBroadley: There seems to be some problems with Sound SE which apparently aren't solvable. As I understand it they don't like music production questions. Don't know if they've decided their scope yet, but I still think Music Production is wide enought for its own subject. DrMayhem might know more about the current status.

Comment: I know that we have not migrated music production questions there, due to them not being welcome.

Comment: Right, this sounds like a good proposal then.

Comment: While I'm not against an SE for music production, there are aspects of this proposal I think need to be refined that seriously conflict with our scope before it makes any sense for us to support it as seen in this [answer and just the questions in general around the propsal](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/20397). I'll probably make a more detailed post about this as an answer later.

Comment: @Dom: I think it's better to support it in order for it to come up, and not get hung up on details. That is one answer, which has one vote. That answer is also showing the tendency to over-analyze and discuss things prematurely on SE. A basic scope of Music Production questions should be reasonably easy to come up with. Then, when and if the community takes off, one could refine scope. To me these often detailed and speculative discussions doesn't seem to lead to good things...

Comment: @Dom: Could you give an example of a current question which would get a very good answer here among the existing example questions? I'm not looking to start an argument. To me the example questions are examples of questions we are not great at answering here, so I want to understand where our views differ.

Comment: If this stuff isn't taken care of it could hurt us and them and it's not just that one answer that shows that potential it's all of them. We will not have control over the scope of the site to fix things like that once it's launched as we'll be different sites. The scope is currently defined as **Proposed Q&A site for musicians, music producers, mixers, and audio engineers** notice the musician line and also notice only 16% of the users there are even registered here which shows most users won't know or care for our scope.

Comment: I think the site should be for musicians, since many of us record our music, but does not consider ourselves in any of the other categories. The only way I see it would hurt this site is if they give significantly better answers to questions that belong here. Whether to ask on "Music: Practice & Performance or "Music Production" should be pretty clear cut in most cases, using a bit of common sense.

Comment: *Music: Practice &Theory...

Comment: And, if it better fits here, we can migrate it over and make it clear that those types of questions are are this SE.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed that proposal, however in looking at the questions I can see challenges.

There is a wide overlap with [Sound Design Stack Exchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) - of the top 20 questions on the proposal, 12 are on topic over at Sound, and 2 would probably work here.

Comment: Well, I think all Music Production questions could fit there, but there seems to be a perennial disagreement about the scope. Maybe things cleared? Quoting from the on topic page of SD: "mixing and recording in a studio from the perspective of the sound tech". That would cater for most questions, but still there has been issues when migrating questions from Music to Sound Design.

Comment: There are many questions that could work here, but we don't have the expertise. My hope was that a new community would attract the knowledge we don't have here.

Comment: Oh, I do agree entirely. I just think that we need to be careful with scope.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the veritable ghost town the music lover site is I doubt splintering the music people on this site again would be worthwhile. Lets first grow the music related sites we have before thinking of adding more of them.

Comment: I can understand this point of view, what I don't see how we will get a new sub-community with a lot of production knowledge here. This site has been around for a while now, and I don't think this will happen by itself. Also, Music Production is a better fit for the SE format than Music Fans.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername for what reasons could we not get new sub-community with a lot of production knowledge here, if you think it would be possible for that community to grow up around a new SE? (genuine question and I'm open to having my mind changed!)

Comment: @topomorto: This is a discussion from 1.5 years ago, and I'm not that active anymore. But one reason could be that music production type guys get the impression that this is the place to discuss different aspects of counterpoint, which they might not be so interested in. But I don't know the state of the stack at this point in time :).

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername The particular proposal linked to in the title is closed, but it has come back: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100727/music-production. I wonder if we should be working to counter that impression?